# Make a table of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

[image]

And I would like the following output:

[image]

So I need the "Date" in seperate columns and the "Days waiting" in the cells below. There are a lot more dates and days waiting, this is just a small example.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].